# Arduino IDE 1.8.13 won't launch properly

Tags: arduino-ide, linux

Recently I have been trying to install Arduino IDE 1.8.13, and I have ran into according problem.
When trying to launch Arduino IDE with ./arduino command it shows according error:

```
./arduino: line 35: /home/wiktor/Downloads/arduino-1.8.13/java/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

I have checked and java file does indeed exist.
I am using 32 bit version of Arduino IDE and 32 bit version of Linux Alpine 3.13.3.

Thanks for all answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: Below, [technician 274](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/75308/the-technician-274) (the original poster) commented:

> It ended up working, after following alpinelinux wiki and installing
> the IDE using flatpak.

---

Part of the problem is how confusing the message is.
`No such file or directory` is not actually referring to the java file.  It's referring to the ld-linux.so interpreter specified in the elf file.

If you run the `file` command on the java executable, you'll see output that looks like:

```
./java/bin/java: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, not stripped
```

If you look for `/lib/ld-linux.so.2`, you're going to find that you don't have one, and that's the file it's complaining about.

Alpine Linux apparently uses [Musl](https://www.musl.com/) and the java binaries were compiled for [glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/), which is normal for desktop Linux.  On a typical desktop Linux system, that the java that ships with the Arduino IDE was compiled for, all kinds of executables make use of ld-linux.so.2.  On your Alpine system, you'll find they're referring to /lib/ld-musl-i386.so.1 instead.  From this vantage point, it's more of a Linux problem than an Arduino one, but I thought it might as well have something of an answer to point people toward relevant looking resources:

- https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Running_glibc_programs
- https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc

You may find it's easier to replace the java interpreter, but that won't be enough, because the Avrdude and GCC binaries will also expect ld-linux.so.2.

In the end, it may be easier to just not use Alpine Linux.

Comment: It ended up working, after following alpinelinux wiki and installing the IDE using flatpak.